# Oracle function to return value from select with union

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add this function to oracle db but it keeps throwing the following errors:

> 10/72   PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'COMMITID'
>
> 12/90   PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'COMMITID'
>
> 14/76   PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'COMMITID'
>
> 17/16   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetLatestProfileChangeDateTime(commitId IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN DATE 
   AS 
   testing DATE;
   BEGIN 
        select max(a) as dateOfChange
        INTO testing
        from
        (
        select max(created_date) a from image_set where reference_id = :commitId and created_date is not null
        union
        select max(date_of_change) a from preferred_agent_info_history where commit_id = :commitId and date_of_change is not null
        union
        select max(date_of_change) a from commit_history where commit_id = :commitId and date_of_change is not null
        )
        
        RETURN testing; 
    END;
```

The inner select statement works fine but when I try to implement it within a function, I can't get it to accept it. I've even tried removing the parameter binding in the select statements for a starting place but it will throw different errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need bind variables in your function; you are using the function parameter in the SQL part of the function, so you can simply refer to it by its name.
For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f1(p IN number) return number is
  2      retVal number;
  3  begin
  4      select :p * 2 into retVal from dual;
  5      return retVal;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for FUNCTION F1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/12     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'P'
```

The right way:

```
SQL> create or replace function f1(p IN number) return number is
  2      retVal number;
  3  begin
  4      select f1.p * 2 into retVal from dual;
  5      return retVal;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select f1(3) from dual;

     F1(3)
----------
         6
```

Comment: to avoid potential problems, I'd recommend specifying the alias, i.e. `select f1.p * 2 into retVal from dual;`